# Add a TextBox below an Inline Shape on MS Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to insert a textbox below a chosen image with Inline text wrapping and position it at the left bottom of the image. I'm using the below code without much success. I'm not too sure whether to use a ShapeRange or an InlineShape. Any pointers?

```
Dim shp As Object
'Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
'Set rng = shp.Anchor
Set shp = Selection.InlineShapes(1)
Set rng = shp.Range

With ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=shp.Left, Top:=(shp.Top + shp.Height), Width:=shp.Width / 3, Height:=shp.Height / 6, Anchor:=rng)
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(186, 14, 29)
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Sabon MT"
    .TextFrame.TextRange = "T"
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for getting the coordinates for the shape from here: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-48831.html

Here's my code:

```
Sub AddTextBox

    Set shp = Selection.InlineShapes(1)
    Set rng = shp.Range       
    Set tb = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(1, fcnXCoord, fcnYCoord + shp.Height, shp.Width, shp.Height / 6)

End Sub

Function fcnXCoord() As Double
    fcnXCoord = Selection.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
End Function

Function fcnYCoord() As Double
    fcnYCoord = Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
End Function
```